# Question about disabled cookie consent (Magento 1.9.3.7)

Tags: cookie, magento1.9.3.7

Normally speaking, the Cookie Restriction Mode is enabled in order to notify visitors that cookies are required for full-featured operations. The message links to the privacy policy for more information, and encourages visitors to click the Allow button to grant consent.

So does this mean that if the Cookie Restriction Mode is disabled, all cookies will be placed by default? I read that for some webshops, no consent is really needed, so I wondered if -in this case- it's enough with disabling the Cookie Restriction Mode, and all cookies would be placed.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off declaration on the admin-cms-static blocks, or edit them (text information).

Cookie are helpful for users and working of magento.

Comment: Hi Alexey; so basically i can turn it off and all cookies will still be placed?

Comment: If you turn off cookies , some of them will still placed. Cookie it is a best way for saving and checkining some data from users webrowser..

Comment: If you are looking for cookie consent module in magento 2 then here is the one https://www.codedecorator.com/magento-2-cookie-notice.html